# How to form this kind of graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create this kind of graph on the basis of user entered data.
the main issue is regarding the display of boxes on the point.
Let me explain you a bit,background does contain a gradient image which resembles to the color of urine the patient want to mention.

Please suggest me something to create this graph.Whole data is need to be fetched dynamically.

[image]

Comment: Without the image there will be no helpful answers and the question may possibly be downvoted.

Comment: You want to create which kind of graph :) ?

Comment: I u want quick solution from stack overflow ppl, you should at least post the link of image :)

Comment: actually i tried to upload the image but the site gave an error that i should have reputation of 10 or more to include image

Answer (score 1):

If none of the many graphing tools out there can help you, you can think about this with plain old HTML :-)

Either a table or absolutely positioned DIVs. If you use a table, you can identify the cell and add a class to give that cell's border a red colour. You can do the same with DIVs. When you print the table cells or DIV to the page, you can identify them with 8-2-27 (unit-month-date) and your JSON data can match the corresponding cell/div and add a class.

Of course this is a bit more work than using an out of the box plugin. But it is possible. I have done a similar thing in the past. I found it easier to do everything on the server side and print the HTML (this was before jQuery had a plugin for everything).

Comment: even if you find something close to this anywhere kindly post it here

Comment: got the solution to the problem using HTML5 canvas tag...thanks for support anyways

Answer (score 0):

gRaphael, JSChart, PlotKit, HighCharts are some common libraries used today to create chart in the client side. You need to provide JSON data and HTML Element only. Remaining task are not needed to be done by you. You can use JFreeChart to create a chart (image) on the server side and send it to the client side.

Comment: HI Atul, I almost looked demos from 20 best java script libraries but didn't find exactly this kind of graph. A candlestick graph found in many libraries, is the closest alternative (although it is used for equity shares' hi-lo graph). But what you are looking for, is not having a readymade solution. But I can say one thing, you can think of building your own code. All the best.